# Extract all occurrences of a word type from a string to a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, parsing

I have a table, tblExample, that has an identity column and a column(varchar), clHTML, that contains HTML data. I need to go through that column for any entry and extract all words that fit this format: 'fileName=[word].png'

For example, an entry for clHTML could have this:

```
'/ImageBrowser/GetImage?fileName=ContactUs2.png" /></p><p class="doc-paragraph">A confirmation message will appear, clicking the OK button will complete the process.</p><p class="doc-paragraph"><img alt="" src="/ImageBrowser/GetImage?fileName=ContactUsConfirmation.png'
```

So I want only ContactUs2.png and ContactUsConfirmation.png in a table for that entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *splitstring* function

```
select left(Split_value,charindex('.png',Split_value)+3) as Result
from yourtable y
Cross apply udf_splitstring ss(clHTML,'fileName=')
Where Split_value like 'fileName=%.png%'
```

There are n number of ways to split a string in sql server. Check the below articles

[Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

[Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Comment: Thanks Prdp! Your solution work, but for the WHERE clause, this works instead:
    Where Split_value like '%.png%'